# vimscript detect piped input

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

It is easy to use vimscript to determine if a filename was specified to vim by using `argc()`. Is there a way to determine if the `-` flag was given to specify piped input was given to vim? It doesn't count piped input as a filename and `argc()` is empty.

**Edit**

Thanks to the wonderful accepted answer below, I have a way to open NerdTree if there are no filenames *and* stndin is not being used.

```
let wmuse_nt = 0
autocmd StdinReadPost * let wmuse_nt = 1
autocmd vimenter * if !argc() && wmuse_nt == 0 | NERDTree | endif
```

Comment: Nice! I think you should take the "edit" portion out of your question, and instead add it as a self-answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use an autocmd to run something before or after vim reads from stdin with the `StdinReadPre` or `StdinReadPost` events. The help is copied below.

```
                                                        StdinReadPost
StdinReadPost                   After reading from the stdin into the buffer,
                                before executing the modelines.  Only used
                                when the "-" argument was used when Vim was
                                started --.
                                                        StdinReadPre
StdinReadPre                    Before reading from stdin into the buffer.
                                Only used when the "-" argument was used when
                                Vim was started --.
```