# Vim: check if running as a pager

Tags: vim, neovim

I searched through Vim's source repository (which includes help doc too) for any references to pager but couldn't find so asking here- Is there a way to see if vim is running as a pager? I'd like to run certain commnands automatically when that happens.

EDIT:  By pager, I mean vim reading from stdin when piped as `vim -`. I use a plugin called `AnsiEsc` mentioned in another vim related question so would like to load that automatically. I would also like to remap some keybindings.

Comment: Vim being a text editor, defining what "running as a pager" means and explaining what you do to toward that end should help us help you.

Comment: Well I meant vim reading from stdin when piped as `vim -`. I use a plugin called AnsiEsc mentioned in another vim related question so would like to load that automatically. I would also like to remap some keybindings.

Comment: Add that information to your question, please.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31548204/vimscript-detect-piped-input/31553281#31553281. 

I have voted to close.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [vimscript detect piped input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31548204/vimscript-detect-piped-input)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to register an autocommand on `StdinReadPre` or `Post`. e.g.

```
" .vimrc
aug StdIn
  au! 
  au StdinReadPost * echomsg "In pager mode!"
aug END
```

I don't see anything else in Vim.

Answer (score 3):

The `StdinReadPost` (TIL) seems to be perfect for your use case but well, here is a makeshift alternative:

```
augroup pager
    autocmd!
    autocmd VimEnter * if v:statusmsg =~ 'stdin' | echomsg "is pager" | endif
augroup END
```